# Installing a package on MRO 3.4.2 error: /bin/sh: /usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++: No such file or directory

Tags: r, macos, clang, llvm-clang, method-resolution-order

I am trying to install a package which finally needs clang. In particular, the error is the following:

```
install.packages("httpuv")
versuche URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-10-15/src/contrib/httpuv_1.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 427638 bytes (417 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 417 KB

Warnung in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz)
  unknown timezone 'default/Europe/Berlin'
* installing *source* package ‘httpuv’ ...
** Paket ‘httpuv’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** libs
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I./http-parser -I./sha1 -I./base64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.2-MRO/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/bin/sh: /usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘httpuv’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.2-MRO/Resources/library/httpuv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
```

In general I have some versions of clang installed. After reading some things about this issue I found out, that "/bin/sh: /usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++:" is not available. Therefore I edit the R makeconf changing the following lines

```
CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=$CXX
CXX14=$CXX
CXX17=$CXX
CXX1X=$CXX
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

to

```
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang++
CXX11=$CXX
CXX14=$CXX
CXX17=$CXX
CXX1X=$CXX
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/lib
```

But nevertheless the installer seems to seek for the other folder...

Do I have to change the folders elsewhere? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Best wishes

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I installed clang 4.0.0 and all the desired folders and files which the installer needs for this package is on the right place. This solution comes from: [http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#bash-clang4](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#bash-clang4)
Therefore, there is no need to edit the makeconf file of R.